# Find if there is a new line starting in the UILabel content at a specific point

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm working on a project where I have a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell that arrange its cell size based on the content that will fits to its UILabel(UITableViewAutomaticDimension).Hence, This UITableView is has expandable collapsable cells ,thus I set the number of lines = 5 if my cell is collapsed. My requirement is to set the number of line = 4 if the fifth line contain a new line. Because of this complication as of now I get an empty space in my fifth line if it has a new line. My code as bellow.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)

            let description = cell.viewWithTag(tableViewCellTags.namelabel) as! UILabel


            description.text = jsondata["text"] as! String
            description.sizeToFit()
            let seeMoreButton = cell.viewWithTag(tableViewCellTags.button) as! UIButton

            seeMoreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.seeMoreClicked(button:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
            cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

            description.numberOfLines = isHealerDetailCollapsed ? 5 : 0


            loadTheInitialLabelText(descriptionContentLbl: description, descriptionSeeMoreBtn: seeMoreButton)
        return cell
        }else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
        }
    }

    func loadTheInitialLabelText(descriptionContentLbl:UILabel,descriptionSeeMoreBtn:UIButton) {
        let DescriptionTextheight = descriptionContentLbl.text?.height(withConstrainedWidth: descriptionContentLbl.frame.width, font: descriptionContentLbl.font)
        //let hac = "nednkewnlkednkewnklew".components(separatedBy: "")

       // descriptionContentLbl.text
        if descriptionContentLbl.intrinsicContentSize.height < DescriptionTextheight! {
            descriptionSeeMoreBtn.isHidden = false
        }else{
            if(isSeemoreVisible){
                descriptionSeeMoreBtn.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}

extension String {

    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)` to remove all the white spaces.

Comment: didnt solve the issue and already tried boss

Comment: This is very confusing... Are you saying: the "description" text could wrap to 12 lines, but when "collapsed" I need to set the label to 5 lines... *unless* there is a new-line in the text that wraps onto the 5th line, so then set it to 4 lines??? So if the text is `1 \n 2 \n 3 \n 4 \n 5 \n` set it to 4 lines, but if that last `\n` is not there, then set it to 5 lines?

Comment: currently im truncating the description text to "5 lines" when its not "collapsed". But at times when I get the Jsondata, the fifth line is a new line(new paragraph), therefore i need to truncate from that point